# TSQL substitution of key words and code blocks

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have blocks of TSQL that I want to create a MACRO for and then reuse in my SQL file.  I want this to be a 'compile' time thing only.

Eg:

```
?set? COMMON = "Field1 int, Field2 char(1),";
?set? MAKEONE = "create table";

MAKEONE XXX (
    COMMON
    Field3 int
);
```

Please dont ask why I would want to ... :)

... it is for SQL Server.

Ok, what about conditional execution of SQL:

```
?set? ISYES = true;

?if? ISYES 
create table AAA (...)
?else?
create table BBB (...)
```

Comment: Why would you want to...

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking makes little sense in SQL terms

Based on your examples:

1. A CREATE TABLE is exactly that: a CREATE TABLE. Why Macro it? You aren't going to substitute "CREATE PROCEDURE".
2. Having "common" fields would indicate poor design

You also have to consider:

- constraints, keys and indexes
- permissions of using dynamic SQL
- the cost of developing a "framework" to do what SQL already does
- permissions of your objects

Now, what is the business problem you are trying to solve?
Instead of asking about your chosen solution...

Edit: question updated as I typed above:

```
IF (a condition)
   EXEC ('CREATE TABLE ...')
ELSE IF (a condition)
   EXEC ('CREATE TABLE ...')
...
```

Note that much of DDL in SQL must be in it's own batch or the first statement in a batch. Hence use of dynamic SQL again

Comment: 1.  My example was just it, an example of substitution ...  2.  Common fields are not bad design ... timestamps etc come to mind.